# OpenCV HoughCircles cvRound

Tags: android, opencv, eclipse-cdt

i have just followed an example on opencv regarding circle detection http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

```
vector<Vec3f> circles;
/// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
/// Draw the circles detected
for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
   Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
   int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
   ...
```

However, im having projekt with eclipse not accepting the function call

**cvRound(circles[i][0])**

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int cvRound(double) '
```

I have tried to add include a number of directories for gnu c and c++ in properties -> c/c++ general -> paths and symbols for example

ndkroot/sources/cxx-stl..../include

the native/jni/include

for opencv etc

But still it wont accept the cvRound function, is there something im missing?

thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

cvRound function is just a rounding function to convert a double value to integer. Two ways:

1- You can make your own rounding function and use it.

```
int Round(double x){
int y;
if(x >= (int)x+0,5)
   y = (int)x++;
else
   y = (int)x;
return y;
}
```

2- Include not only C++, but also C API of opencv. (include/opencv/)